# Negative values in Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-process

I'm trying to make some sense of the following definition:

A collection of random variables $\{ N_t \}$$_{t \geq 0}$ is called a Poisson process with rate parameter $\lambda > 0$ if

- $N_0 = 0$
- $N_{t_2} - N_{t_1}$ and $N_{t_4} - N_{t_3}$ are independent for all $0 \leq t_1 < t_2 \leq t_3 < t_4$
- For all $t \geq 0$ and $h > 0$, we have $P(N_{t+h} - N_t = 1) = \lambda h + o(h)$ and $P(N_{t+h} - N_t \geq 2) = o(h)$

Now my question is, does this definition imply that $N_t \geq 0$ for all $t$? I know that this must obviously be true since they represent counts, but how do you actually get this from the definition?

Comment: If you're asking if a random variable can take negative values, it can. Take a random variable describing the price of some stock with bench value.

Comment: Not asking about a general random variable here. I was wondering how the above definition excludes negative values for the variables.

Comment: I wonder whether the difference between two independent conventional Poisson processes (perhaps defined with the third bullet being $N_{t+h}-N_t \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda h)$ to avoid circularity)  would satisfy your definition.  If so, negative values for the difference would have positive probability.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the definition is incomplete and you may need an extra condition, for example that $P(N_{t+h} - N_t \lt 0) = 0$ or perhaps at most $o(h)$ in the third bullet, or that $P(N_{t+h} - N_t =0) = 1-\lambda h +o(h)$.

As an example, suppose $L_t$ is a conventional Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ and independently $M_t$ a conventional Poisson process with parameter $\mu$, with $N_t=L_t-M_t$.

Then the first two conditions are satisfied.  So too is the third, since when $h \to 0^+$:

- $P(N_{t+h} - N_t = 1) = \lambda h + o(h)$
- $P(N_{t+h} - N_t \ge 2) = o(h)$
- $P(N_{t+h} - N_t = 0) = 1-\lambda h-\mu h + o(h)$
- $P(N_{t+h} - N_t = -1) = \mu h + o(h)$
- $P(N_{t+h} - N_t \le -2) = o(h)$

In this case $N_t$ would have a [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) with parameters $\lambda t$ and $\mu t$, and would have a positive probability of being negative for any $t>0$, so would not be a conventional Poisson process.